# OpenCV - Java - How to remove some pixels around a cluster

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a project where I need to identify certain areas of the image. After processing the image and removing all the unnecessary things I finally get the area which I need as shown in the image (area inside the green circle).

I am unable to draw a circle around that area using OpenCV. I am currently using the Java version of OpenCV. If someone can point me to the right direction on how to implement that green circle over the image, it will be very helpful.

Things I have tried to detect that area.
blob detector - Did not achieve much.
Cluster - Same as blob detector.
HoughCircles - Draws unnecessary circles in the image.
FindContour - Did not draw anything since it is not a perfect circle, ellipse or any other well known polygon.

I appreciate your help.

[image: After processing I want image to look as shown below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem. I used the feature detector from the OpenCV library and gave the right threshold to the detector. This did the trick for me. The code in Java looks like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        //Validation whether a file name is passed to the function
        if(args.length == 0){
            System.out.println("here...");
            log.error("No file was passed to the function");
            throw new IOException();
        }

        //Read the image from the input
        Mat inputMat = Highgui.imread(args[0],Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        //Create a feature detector. In this case we are using SURF (Speeded-Up Robust Features) detector. 
        MatOfKeyPoint objectKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);

        //A temporary file is created to input Hessian Threshold to the SURF detector
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("config", ".yml");
        String settings = "%YAML:1.0\nhessianThreshold: 7000.\noctaves: 3\noctaveLayers: 4\nupright: 0\n";
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile, false);
        writer.write(settings);
        writer.close();

        //Read the configuration from the temporary file to assign the threshold for the detector
        featureDetector.read(tempFile.getPath());

        //Detect the features in the image provided
        featureDetector.detect(inputMat, objectKeyPoints);

        //Iterate through the list of key points detected in the previous step and find the Key Point with the largest size
        List<KeyPoint> objectKeyPointList = objectKeyPoints.toList();
        KeyPoint impKeyPoint = new KeyPoint();

        for(int i=0; i<objectKeyPointList.size(); i++){
            if(impKeyPoint == null){
                impKeyPoint = objectKeyPointList.get(i);
            }
            else if(impKeyPoint.size < objectKeyPointList.get(i).size){
                impKeyPoint = objectKeyPointList.get(i);
            }
        }

        //If the size of the Key Point is greater than 120 then reduce the size to 120 and if the size is less than 120 then increase to 120 
        if(impKeyPoint.size > 120){
            KeyPoint tempKeyPoint = new KeyPoint();
            tempKeyPoint = impKeyPoint;
            tempKeyPoint.size = 120;
            impKeyPoint = tempKeyPoint;
        }
        else if(impKeyPoint.size < 120){
            KeyPoint tempKeyPoint = new KeyPoint();
            tempKeyPoint = impKeyPoint;
            tempKeyPoint.size = 120;
            impKeyPoint = tempKeyPoint;
        }

        //Convert the Key Point to MatOfKeyPoint since drawKeyPoints accepts only MatOfKeyPoint
        MatOfKeyPoint impMatOfKeyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint(impKeyPoint);

        //Mat for drawing the circle in the image
        Mat outputImage = new Mat(inputMat.rows(), inputMat.cols(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

        //Green color for the circle
        Scalar greenCircle = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);

        //Draw the circle around the optic nerve when detected
        Features2d.drawKeypoints(inputMat, impMatOfKeyPoint, outputImage, greenCircle, Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

        //Write the image to a file
        Highgui.imwrite("surf_keypoints.png", outputImage);
    }catch(Exception e){
        log.fatal(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Hope this is helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

1. Opening in order to clean the image from all the thin/elongate patterns.
2. Connected component labeling in order to count the remaining patterns
3. Size counting of each remaining pattern
4. The biggest pattern is the one you want to circle.

Note: is you want to perfectly preserve the pattern, you can replace the opening by an opening by reconstruction (erosion + geodesic reconstruction).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can do the step one. I sort of tried step 2, it takes a lot of time to process if the connected component is 2 pass. Do you have links to some examples where I can make it more faster? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Here is a link to a french page of the Union-Find algorithm developed in Java, but it's really easy to re-implement it in C++: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d480842/general-developpement/algorithme-mathematiques/contribuez/java-etiquettage-composantes-connexes-union-find/

Comment: I will implement this in my project and let you know what happens. Thank you.